# Activating a Conda Enviroment in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, conda

Probably an extremely trivial question. I created an environment in conda and now want to run a script in pycharm. what is the command line to activate said conda environment so that I can use work in it on pycharm?

Comment: If conda env is specified as project interpreter, then activation will be done automatically by PyCharm before running a script

Answer (score 0):

By default, the command is `source activate your_env_name`

On Windows, it should be `conda activate your_env_name` instead

Comment: Hmm when I write these in the terminal, I either get:
"source is not recognized as an internal or external command" or "conda" is not recognized as an internal external command".

Comment: Is conda set as your current project interpreter? Under prefererences -> project -> project interpreter. If the interpreter path isn't the conda env you had set up, you should add it and then see if it works.

Comment: @mk2080 "conda activate your_env_name" is the OS independent and newer way.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: First know the path of python and conda that you want to use. If you don't know, you can get the path(s) on windows command prompt by:

```
>where conda

>where python
```

Step2: Press Ctrl+Alt+S to open the project Settings/Preferences and go to Project  | Python Interpreter. Then click the gear icon and select Add.
In the left-hand pane of the Add Python Interpreter dialog, select Conda Environment.
Select **Existing environment**
Click Select an interpreter and specify a paths to python and Conda executable (the paths you obtained in Step1).